# Xib is not showing some properties

Tags: ios, xib

I have a `xib` with some buttons, views, etc, and the `xib` was working fine but suddenly every time i add a button or any other stuff to that `xib`, it doesn't show it, i think that is not `initializing` it but i don't know what to do.

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
```

that is the nib initialization, there is something to do in there?

Comment: Did you change the nib name or change the string you pass into the init method? Make sure the string you pass is correct.

Answer (score 0):

print nibNameOrNil and check if it is the same name

Comment: Yes it is the same name

Comment: Check the frames of control that you are adding on screen, print these frames.